# Why won't my checkboxes appear selected when I pass the correct data into them?

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

So I have a table that is suppose to reflect data that is passed in from sql and one of these data fields is a boolean that is supposed to be shown by a checkbox

From what I can tell I have set up the checkbox correctly but it still will not show as true. I also had it print out the value next to the check box to make sure the correct value was being passed.

```
<input name="DidPass" type="checkbox" ng-model="task.DidPass" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">{{task.DidPass}}
```

Here is a picture of the result:

[image: mycode]

Comment: I needed to add the ng-checked field to my checkbox and it cleared up the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-checked` directive of angular like following:

```
<input name="DidPass" type="checkbox" ng-checked="task.DidPass == 1" ng-model="task.DidPass" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">{{task.DidPass}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what my issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the `ng-checked` directive ?
See [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-checked.asp)

Comment: I did need to add the ng-checked directive into the checkbox statement